# SUM a column by IF criteria in second column - Google Sheets

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a table like this with two columns (`A` and `B`) - the first column contains times, the second column contains "checkboxes":

```
12:00:00 x  
10:00:00 
13:00:00 x
```

I want to SUM up all times with an "x" so the outcome should be `25:00:00`.

I tried with `=VLOOKUP(A4;A1:B3;1;FALSE)` the key is `A4=x` sadly this does not work! (x was not found)

Comment: Is this an excel OR a google-sheets question? Usually it can't be both.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using (if at all)?  More importantly, do you have access to [the `SUMIFS` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMIF` is what you're looking for:

```
=SUMIF(B:B, "=x", A:A)
```

Where `B:B` is the range to match to the condition `=x` and `A:A` is the range to sum when the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXT(SUMIF(B:B, "=x", A:A), "[h]:mm:ss")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=TEXT(SUM(FILTER(A:A, B:B="x")), "[h]:mm:ss")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IF(B:B="x", A:A, )), "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

[image]

---

```
=TEXT(SUM(QUERY(A:B, "select A where B ='x'")), "[h]:mm:ss")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT((B:B="x")*(A:A)), "[h]:mm:ss")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$3="X")*($A$1:$A$3))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100)*(B1:B100="x"))
```

[image]

with the proper formatting applied.